# Random Number Generator

Tags: vb.net, random

I use the following function

```
CInt(Math.Floor((99999999 - 10000000 + 1) * Rnd())) + 10000000)
```

To get random numbers with length of 8 digits...
Ok I get sum of different numbers with the length I want when I run this function in debugging mode
But when I run my program that function

```
Dim rguun As String = CInt(Math.Floor((99999999 - 10000000 + 1) * Rnd())) + 10000000)
```

Always gives me back the same number
Why is that happen?

Comment: when did ints become strings....?

Comment: Call [`Randomize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt.aspx), once at the start of your program, without passing it a value. Your random number generator would seem to be seeded with the same value each time.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes that was it... I saw it when I read the article from Microsoft but I forgot to put it in my code...

Comment: Or maybe you should simply create a `Random` object and call its `Next` method, which how you should be generating random numbers in VB.NET.  We're not in VB6 any more Toto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub randomnumber()
    Dim rndNumber As String = ""
    Dim rnd As New Random
    For n As Integer = 0 To 7
        rndNumber &= Rnd.Next(0, 9)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well the issue in my case was to put the `Randomize` in my code. That was I forgot to put it... Thank you very much for your answer.